# Parse datetime from string data type to datetime data type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert 'Date Column's Data type from string as it was originally imported from the CSV file, into datetime data type with the read csv command line and remove the time, i.e. I want to keep the date.

```
data = {'Name':  ['Mark', 'Sam'],
        'Date': ['07Feb2021 00:00:00', '06April2020 00:00:00']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Name','Date',...])

print (df)
```

Output:

```
Name    Date
Mark   07Feb2021 00:00:00
Sam    06April2020 00:00:00
```

I tried this code and it worked i.e. when I did df.info() the date column data type was datetime64[ns] , then when I restarted the kernel and run all the data type defaulted back to Object again , i.e. same original format

## Dependencies Imported :

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
```

## Code:

```
def parse_dt(x):
    return [np.datetime64 (dt.strptime(date_item, '%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S').date()) for date_item in X]
    
df=pd.read_csv(r'DataFile.csv', parse_dates=['Date Column'], date_parser=parse_dt)
        
df
```

Comment: Make a [mcve] including small .csv file input sample and expected vs. actual output.

Answer (score 3):

You can read the dataframe from the csv as is, and then use the [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method to convert the desired column into a datetime format.

I will show an example, say i have a Dataframe with a column 'date', running the following code will transform the strings in to datetime object:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01/06/1901', '30/11/1901', '12/05/1901', '01/06/1901']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: I tried that and did not work....Is there anything am I missing in my code?

Comment: Can you show what you tried and how exactly it did not work?

Comment: I tried the code above, then did df.info() to show the datatype of the columns. at first I got Data Column data type as datetime64[ns], then when I restarted the Kernel I got the same original format i.e. Object

Comment: I edited my answer to give an example, if this provides an answer please mark is as 'accepted'

Comment: it did not work....The Original date format is like this 07Feb2021 00:00:00

Comment: The Goal is to include this within the read csv command as shown above

Comment: Instead of writing the format specified in the example, write this:
`df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: If you insist on including in the line you can change your function `parse_dt` to the following thing:
`parse_dt = lambda x:datetime.strptime(x, %d%b%Y %H:%M:%S)`
additional examples can be found [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/4-tricks-you-should-know-to-parse-date-columns-with-pandas-read-csv-27355bb2ad0e)

Comment: @ Ofek Glick I got error message date format does not match

Comment: Still showing data type as Object and Not datetime

Comment: Can you edit your post to show all the trials you’ve done including what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is working properly now

when I did df.info() for some reason it was showing the original data type i.e. object as if the code had been not applied, but when i did df.dtypes()  it showed the desired data type i.e. datetime64[ns] so the code is correct and accurate, i.e it can be used for similar use cases where you have a datetime as a string and you want to convert to datetime64  format .....thanks for those who tried to help!

Comment: Please share your solution with the community by editing your post.

Comment: The code above is the correct solution, i did not make any changes...when I did df.info() for some reason it was showing the data type as Object as if no change had been applied to it, but when I did df.dtypes() it returned the desired data type i,.e. datetime64[ns]....please let me know if you have any question